# What is the difference between stunnel and sshuttle

Tags: linux, ssl, ssh, openssl, stunnel

Can someone explain to me the benefits of using one over the other? Are they comparable?

I understand that `sshuttle` acts as a proxy for outbound communication, however can it also be used to forward connections?

For instance, `stunnel` can be used as a reverse proxy for tunneling data outside of my network. Is this something that can be done with `sshuttle`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: These tools have only a few overlapping use cases. It is completely unknown what you are trying to achieve and like jww@ already said this is unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between these two is the level where do they work. You can achieve the same security with the `sshuttle` with both, because it works on underlying level of `stunnel`. But for using `stunnel` you usually need special setup, unlike for the other, which just work on what is provided (underlying level).

- `stunnel` is based on SSL protocol and works on TCP (layer 4).
- `shuttle` creates TUN devices using `SSH` protocol (virtual network devices) “point-to-point” (layer 3) or “ethernet” (layer 2).

To understand the difference, have a look at the [ISO/OSI description of layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Description_of_OSI_layers):

[image]